# Python regex for searching substring

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract substrings from a long string in python3

```
def get_data(text):
    initials = text.split()[1]
    names = re.search(initials+'(.*)EMP',text).group(1).lstrip().title()

    return initials, names
```

I need the following outputs

```
x,y = get_data('J JS JOHN SMITH EMP 223456')
JS
John Smith 

x,y = get_data('J JB JOE BLOGGS CONT 223456')
JB
Joe Bloggs

x,y = get_data('J JS JOHN SMITH 223456')
JS
John Smith
```

I can do it with either EMP or CONT but am struggling to do it with EMP OR CONT OR 'None'
I'm new to regex hence help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do a split and then search.

You can use a single regex in `re.findall` or `re.search` or `re.match`:

```
^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(.+?)(?:\s+(?:EMP|CONT))?\s+\d+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOOrGa/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespaces and capture in group #1
- `\s+`: Must be followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any character and capture in group #2
- `(?:\s+(?:EMP|CONT))?`: optionally match `EMP` or `CONT` after 1+ whitespaces
- `\s+\d+`: Followed by 1+ whitespaces and 1+ digits